# Using Input Box to return ActiveDirectory Information

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, active-directory

I have the following Code so the User can enter their domain before the program runs.
The resulting textfile does not output the users..just the word Schema...

EDIT 1: Updated to include all code. I now can run it and it returns a text file that lists
OU=_USERS
OU=_GROUPS
OU=_ETC
ETC ETC

```
Sub PrintUserNames()
    'Declare Command
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()
    'Nameint Place to Write file
    Dim userFile As String = "C:\DomainUsers.txt"
    Dim fileExists As Boolean = File.Exists(userFile)

    'Use Input Box for domain entry
    Dim message, Title, defaultValue As String
    Dim myValue As Object
    message = "Enter your Domain Name"
    Title = "Domain Name Entry"
    defaultValue = "Enter Domain Name"
    myValue = InputBox(message, Title, defaultValue)
    'Get List of all users on Domain using WinNT
    'Replacement Command
    Dim ReplaceCommand1 As String = de.Path.Replace("***", myValue) = "WinNT://""***"""
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open(userFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        For Each d As DirectoryEntry In de.Children()
            sw.WriteLine(d.Name)
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Edited to reflect AD information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tip Filburt.
I just threw out the actually actually making a replacement command and just using it as shown below.

```
Dim de As New DirectoryEntry()
    Dim DomainName As Object
    'Use Input Box for domain entry if desired   
    Dim messageOK, messageCan, Title, defaultValue As String
    messageOK = "Enter Domain and Click OK
    Title = "Domain Name Entry"
    defaultValue = "Enter Domain Name"
    DomainName = InputBox(messageOK, Title, defaultValue)
    de.Path = "WinNT://***".Replace("***", DomainName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing your placeholder `***` before you (re)asign it.

```
Dim ReplaceCommand1 As String = de.Path.Replace("***", myValue)
de.Path = "WinNT://***"
```

Depending on where you create `de` you can simply remove the line containing `de.Path = "WinNT://***"`

Comment: Now exports a text file with OU information? Edited to include all code (after modification)

Comment: @harper What values/AD entries do you want to export? The OUs you list in your updated post are to usual top level AD entries. Your `For Each` loop iterates over those children but no entries at a deeper level.

Comment: Just looking to export user names, I just think I had to much going on. I went back to square one and did it in a simpler way.